# How to show ampersand (&) symbol in python?

Tags: python, wxpython

if I do:

```
self.a= wx.Button(self, -1, "Hi&Hello")
```

I get button named: `HiHello`
it ignores the `&` symbol.
How can I fix it?

Comment: tried it alrady. it gives `Hi\Hello`

Comment: I know that.... but the & is in the name... not as shortcut key board.  `\n` is also spaciel but if you want to actually see `\n` there is a specific string that can generate it.

Comment: what about r"Hi&Hello"?

Comment: @PawełKordowski: it's not *Python* that assigns meaning to the ampersand. Using a raw string literal (which is *syntax*, not an object type) will not make any difference here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`&` is a special marker in GUI labels for buttons and menu items. It defines the [standard keyboard mnemonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_shortcut#Keyboard_mnemonic) for that element.

You can escape it by doubling the character:

```
self.a = wx.Button(self, -1, "Hi&&Hello")
```

Comment: Plus one. The quiz of the day: how do you accelerate the ampersand? Answers on a postcard?

Comment: @Bathsheba: guessing: three ampersands? `&&&`

Comment: "standard keyboard shortcut for that element"? What does this mean?

Comment: @LostCrotchet: different windowing systems have different conventions, but you can usually use a keyboard shortcut to active that specific menu item; like `CTRL-S` or `Cmd-S` for `&Save`, etc.

Comment: @LostCrotchet: I've added a link and corrected the term.